# express. js findById with react

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express

if I would like to search for a post using (express. js, MongoDB ) findById, how can I do this with react

> Block quote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an API with express where create the search with MongoDB and return the data, after that, across from React you make the request

Comment: if my url looks like this way '/ index /: id' then in react I have to take it with fetch?

Comment: you can do that, for example, you create an API with express with this url like /api/user, then with React you can do window.fetch('/api/user'), and this request return your data, you can use axios or superagent too, if you don't like use window.fetch